# Using two wouldn't haves

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, would-have-been

Can I use two **wouldn't have** in one sentence? For example:

> If it hadn't been for him, she wouldn't have been accepted in the university, and thus, she wouldn't have been able to get a decent job.

Is that correct?

Comment: What makes you think it might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. You have two main clauses coordinated by ***and***.

> If it hadn't been for him, she wouldn't have been accepted in the university,

***and thus***

> (if it hadn't been for him,) she wouldn't have been able to get a decent job.

You have two conditional clauses merged into one, which is why it may be confusing for you.